# Easiest way to get Json / Collection through Meteor Iron Router

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm creating a set of routes, for example

`/` - should render home page template

`/items` - should items page template

`/items/weeARXpqqTFQRg275` - should return item from MongoDB with given _id

This is example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
Router.route('items/:_id', function () {
  var item = return myItems.find(:_id);
  this.render(item);
});
```

**[update - solved]**
solved this by using `Router.map` on server side instead of `Router.route`

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('post', {
    path: 'items/:_id',
    where: 'server',
    action: function(){
      var id = this.params._id;
      var json = myItems.findOne({_id: id});
      this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      this.response.end(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what is your question ? what do you want to achieve ? Kindly elaborate.
Thanks.

Comment: get result of myItems.find(weeARXpqqTFQRg275) after requesting myapplication.com/items/weeARXpqqTFQRg275

Comment: Did you have a look at the [this Guide section](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, it seems you want to get the `_id` parameter from the url and don't know how. It's stored on `this.params`, so it's `this.params._id`.

Second, the first parameter you should send to `find` is a MongoDB query that in your case would be `{ _id: this.params._id }`.

Third, that's not how you render something in Iron Router. The string parameter on the render method is the **name** of the template you want to render, not the item.

Assuming that `myItems` is a valid collection and your template is called `showItem`, your code should be something like:

```
Router.route('items/:_id', {
  name: 'showItem',
  data: function () {
    return myItems.find({ _id: this.params._id });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah that might be a solution - after router matches defined path it renders template with data loaded from a function. I will mark it as Correct answer, but if anyone would need to render a pure JSON object instead of website, please check my post update at the top. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('items/:myItemId', {
        data: function(){
            return myItems.findOne({_id: this.params.myItemId});
        }
    });
});
```

good luck!

Comment: I have already found a solution (check [edit] below question), but Your solution looks much shorter, I will check it too :)

Comment: That is impressive, although rather complicated. If it works. I just remembered I also use router.map I will edit my answer for you.